# Console crash towards the end of Dark Brotherhood questline

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

***** Spoilers below of Dark Brotherhood questline ***

In the Dark Brotherhood Sanctuary;

> ... after the quest to kill the emperor completes, you find Nazir and kill the guy fighting him - you then decide that you must both escape the sanctuary quickly as it's burning - during which time the Night Mother speaks to you and tells you to join her as it's your only chance of salvation.

When I do this, it starts a cut-scene and the screen goes dark. You then hear what *appears* to sound like the building collapsing - at this point my Console freezes and requires a hard power-off/power-on. I retried 2 further times and it appears to be persistent and permanent.

Other than dropping everything that I'm carrying and trying again, is there much I can do to fix it? I was kinda hoping for a New-Vegas style "put on a cowboy hat and enter the strip!" style solution! :)

Comment: You can still try to put on a cowboy hat ^^. Perhaps it helps, although I do not know where to find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - I ended up solving this myself by simply waiting 5-10 minutes, which (somehow) eventually kickstarts it back into action. During this time the Xbox dashboard is inaccessible, there's no control at all.

Comment: Sounds to me like the disk is messed up. Is it scratched or dusty? I've never heard of an Xbox system glitch like this, unless you've done something like hacking.

Comment: Neither! I found quite a few examples via YouTube of this situation too after doing more digging, its fairly widespread. Disk is fine and console is pretty new.

Comment: Really? Wow, I actually find a glitch like this in a commercial game rather sad... Oh Bethesda!

Comment: Had same issue, many thanks for you documenting your fix - it came back for me after about a minute. I can understand them maybe wanting you to think your dead however the fact the screen is completely black really does make you think your consoles crashed (and the dash not working makes this even more so.).

Comment: Sweet, glad it came back to you too :)

Comment: +1 I thought it had crashed but waiting worked